# Find and string getting - string indices must be integers

Tags: python

Can someone tell me what is wrong with this code.  I keep getting string indices must be integers and I have tried everything I can think of.  Its actually in an if statement but I stripped it down to this to see if i could find the problem.  The Find is returning 23 for the string I am searching.  I added the int function to see if that would fix it.

```
stringloc = 1
stringloc = text.find('http')
print(stringloc)
print(text[0, int(stringloc)])
```

Here is the return message
print(text[0, int(stringloc)])
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Do you know what `text[0, int(stringloc)]` is doing? Maybe you wanted `text[:int(stringloc)]`?

Comment: I want it to start at first character and search till http is in the string.  

I have a string.  I want to search for a substring, but only in the string up to the http

Comment: So, you wanted `text[:int(stringloc)]`.

Comment: sorry not sure how that got duplicated

Comment: I guess I am not sure exactly what your line of code does.  Very new to python

Comment: Try looking at a tutorial or the documentation before asking a question, then. Some good sources are here: https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F

Comment: Well that worked.  Thank you.  Can you tell me what that line of code means.  I see what it does but not sure what the ":' does and I am assuming the find command defaults to 0 if only one arg is provided

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation

Comment: I searched for hours before posting

Comment: Like I said, learn the language before you start programming with it...

Answer (score 0):

You may wanted use index like that [start:end]

```
In [1]: text="this is the text for demo"

In [2]: stringloc=text.find('text')

In [3]: stringloc
Out[3]: 12

In [4]: print(text[0:stringloc])
this is the
```

In [5]: